# BigQuery Unexpected error "(" when creating TEMP TABLE

Tags: google-bigquery, temp-tables

I got a Syntax error: Unexpected "(" at [2:1] whilst trying to create a Temp Table in Big Query. When i try to remove the "(" I get Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "string" at [3:17]. How do i correct this in BigQuery.

```
CREATE TABLE #PercentPopulationVaccinated
(
      continent string,
      location string,
      date datetime,
      population int64,
      new_vaccinations int64,
      AccumVaccinations int64
)

INSERT INTO #PercentPopulationVaccinated
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population,vac.new_vaccinations
, SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location,dea.date) AS AccumVaccinations
FROM `portfolio-project-356519.Covid.CovidDeaths` dea
JOIN `portfolio-project-356519.Covid.CovidVaccinations`  vac
      ON dea.location = vac.location
      AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL

SELECT *, (AccumVaccinations/population)*100
FROM #PercentPopulationVaccinated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right way to create a temporary table based on the code you shared.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE PercentPopulationVaccinated
(
      continent string,
      location string,
      date datetime,
      population int64,
      new_vaccinations int64,
      AccumVaccinations int64
);

INSERT INTO PercentPopulationVaccinated
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population,vac.new_vaccinations
, SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location,dea.date) AS AccumVaccinations
FROM `portfolio-project-356519.Covid.CovidDeaths` dea
JOIN `portfolio-project-356519.Covid.CovidVaccinations`  vac
      ON dea.location = vac.location
      AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL;

SELECT *, (AccumVaccinations/population)*100
FROM PercentPopulationVaccinated;
```